# Why wont my code call the next subroutine when x == n? (python 3.5.0)

Tags: python

```
def teacher_student(): #defines subroutine
 global t_s #globalizes variable
t_s = "" # sets variable to null
while t_s not in ["T","S","t","s"]: # creates array/list and starts the while loop
     t_s = input ("Are you a T or an S? ").upper() #asks the user to input weather they are a T or an S
     while t_s == "S": 
         welcome()

def welcome():
    print (Welcome!)
```

This code will not call the subroutine even if I enter s or S. sorry if its a simple answer I'm new to programing, Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `input ("Are you a T or an S? ").upper` to do? You don't even call the method `upper()`, nor do you assign the returned value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, which adds an action for both good paths, T and S. It also changes your `input()` method to `raw_input()` to protect against input evil in python 2.x

```
def welcome(who):
   if who == "S":
       print "Welcome, student!"
    else:
       print "Welcome, teacher!"


def teacher_student():  # defines subroutine
   userinput = ""  # sets variable to null
   while userinput not in ["T","S"]:  # creates array/list and starts the while loop
       userinput = raw_input("Are you a T or an S?")  # asks the user to input weather they are a T or an S
       userinput = userinput.upper()
       if userinput == "S":
          welcome(userinput)
       if userinput == "T":
           welcome(userinput)

teacher_student()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise Shawn. I will try to avoid global vars if possible I the future but it still does not call the next subroutine and continues to ask if I am T or an S.

Comment: are you, by any chance, running python 2? Anyway, I moved to a safer method in case and added some more paths. Good luck.